# Copying Files using System Calls

Tags: c

Estou com problemas a utilizar as funções write(), read(), close(), open() para copiar um ficheiro de texto para um novo ficheiro (previamente criado).

Depois de alguma pesquisa que fiz obtive o seguinte código:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char ch;
  // FILE *source, *dest;
int n, iDest, iSource;

if(argc!=3){
    exit(1);
}
   iSource = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

   if (iSource == -1)
   {
      exit(1);
   }

   iDest = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY);

   if (iDest == -1)
   {
      close(iSource);
      exit(1);
   }
    while (n = read(iSource, &ch, 1) > 0){
  write(iDest, &ch, 128);
}

close(iSource);
    close(iDest);

   return 0;
}
```

Inicialmente tinha 2 erros a dizer que O_RDONLY e O_WONLY não estavam declarados. Depois de uma pesquisa decidi utilizar "#include fcntl.h" mas continuo a ter problemas. Desta vez o que acontece quando abro o ficheiro de destino é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto está errado:

```
while (n = read(iSource, &ch, 1) > 0)
{
  write(iDest, &ch, 128);
}
```

você está lendo 1 byte e escrevendo 128.

UPDATE:
o código acima também está errado por causa da precedência de operadores: do jeito que está, é como se estivesse escrito

```
while (n = (read(iSource, &ch, 1) > 0))
{
  write(iDest, &ch, 128);
}
```

sendo que o correto é forçar a ordem de execução explicitamente com os parênteses:

```
while ((n = read(iSource, &ch, 1)) > 0)
{
  write(iDest, &ch, 128);
}
```

Assumindo que você quer fazer a cópia em blocos de 128 bytes, é preciso fazer as seguintes alterações:

```
...
char ch[128];
...
...
...
while ((n = read(iSource, ch, 128)) > 0)
{
  write(iDest, ch, n);
}
```

Quanto à mensagem "the Document was not UTF-8 valid", use um editor que aceite qualquer conteúdo, e não apenas arquivos com conteúdo UTF-8. Poderia ser por exemplo o editor "gvim".

Comment: Muito obrigado! Mas sim o meu problema estava na leitura de bytes. Eu queria apenas ler um de cada vez e ao copiar de um código antigo esqueci-me de alterar.

Comment: você poderia marcar a resposta como aceita por favor ? é o símbolo ✓à esquerda, ali logo embaixo da flechinha para baixo